# Match everything except for characters within quotes

Tags: regex, perl

After some playing around I came up with a way to capture characters within single/double quotes:

```
['"](?:[^'"]*?(?:\\")*)*["']
```

Not sure if this is entirely correct. In any event, I am now trying to match everything BUT these.

Example:

`'stringA' '\"stringB\"' variableA variableB`

The above regex matches: `'stringA'` `'\"stringB\"'`

I would like to match `variableA` `variableB`

Is there a way I can achieve this with `Perl`? I was trying to use `negative/positive lookahead/behinds` but I encountered issues as my `lookbehind` had `\s*` which was not allowed.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the PCRE verb `(*SKIP)(*F)`,

```
['"](?:[^'"]*?(?:\\")*)*["'](*SKIP)(*F)|\S+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nX9aI9/7)

- `['"](?:[^'"]*?(?:\\")*)*["']` Matches strings within double or single quotes.
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` Causes the preceding pattern to fail. And try to match the pattern that was in the right side of `|` operator from the remaining strings.
- `\S+` Matches one or more non-space characters except the double or single quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a long complicated regex like the following:

```
my @words = split m{
    ' (?: [^'\\]* | \\. )* ' (*SKIP)(*F)
    |
    " (?: [^"\\]* | \\. )* " (*SKIP)(*F)
    |
    \s+
}x, $_;
```

However, I would recommend using [`Text::ParseWords`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/ParseWords.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::ParseWords;

while (<DATA>) {
    my @words = parse_line(qr{\s+}, 0, $_);

    print "$_\n" for @words;
}

__DATA__
'stringA' '\"stringB\"' variableA variableB
```

Outputs:

```
stringA
\"stringB\"
variableA
variableB
```